# Generate Code Climate reports from CMake / clang warnings

Tags: c++, cmake, gitlab, continuous-integration, code-climate

We have a large CMake-based C++ project in Gitlab, using Gitlab CI, and it would be really nice to be able to see compiler warnings/errors in the [Gitlab UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#code-quality-widget). To get that to work, it seems [Gitlab requires](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#implementing-a-custom-tool) the report to be generated in the [codeclimate format](https://github.com/codeclimate/platform/blob/690633cb2a08839a5bfa350ed925ddb6de55bbdc/spec/analyzers/SPEC.md).

It seems like it would be fairly straightforward to generate a code climate report from the build logs, but that also seems rather fragile as the output could vary across compilers / compiler versions. It also seems like the sort of integration that someone would have already done and integrated into CMake.

Is there a good way to generate CodeClimate reports from CMake? Ideally I would like it to include `clang`, `gcc`, and `clang-tidy` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [CodeChecker](https://github.com/Ericsson/codechecker). It supports analyzing with `clang-tidy` and parsing the results into a CodeClimate report which is described here: https://codechecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gitlab_integration/#using-codechecker-parse